# Ajustar modal bootstrap un poco mas grande

Tags: bootstrap

tengo el siguinte modal:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
```

y se ve de la siguinte manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo ajustarlo de forma responsive, para que se vea mejor? Gracias!

EDIT: MODAL COMPLETO

```
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////// MODAL ///////////////////////////////////// -->
<div id="modal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form id="formgrupofamiliar" method="post">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nombref">Nombre</label>
              <input  autocomplete="nope" type="text" class="form-control" name="nombref" id="nombref" placeholder="Nombre familiar">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="apellidof">Apellido</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="apellidof" placeholder="Apellido" id="apellidof">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="vinculo">Vinculo</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="vinculo" placeholder="Vinculo" id="vinculo">
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="celular">Fecha nacimiento</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechanacimiento" id="fechanacimiento">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tel/cel">Tel/Cel</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="telcel" placeholder="Tel/Cel" id="telcel">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--  FIN PRIMER ROW -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="ocupacion">Ocupacion</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ocupacion" id="ocupacion" placeholder="Ocupación">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="ingreso-mensual">Ingreso mensual estimativo</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="ingreso" placeholder="Ingreso mensual estimativo" id="ingreso">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="comentario-ingreso">Comentario ingreso</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="comentarioingreso" placeholder="Comentario ingreso" id="comentarioingreso">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <!--  FIN SEGUNDO ROW -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="checkbox2" name="cbox2">¿Es beneficiario de beca,plan o programa Nacional, provincial o municipal? Describa</label>
              <textarea class="md-textarea form-control" id="ttarea2" name="ttarea2" rows="2" cols="60" maxlength="100" disabled></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        <!--  FIN TERCER ROW -->
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox3" value="checkbox3" name="cbox3">¿Tiene alguna discapacidad? Describa</label>
              <textarea class="md-textarea form-control" id="ttarea3" name="ttarea3" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="100" disabled></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox4" value="checkbox4" name="cbox4">¿Tiene N° CUD? Indique</label>
              <textarea class="md-textarea form-control" id="ttarea4" name="ttarea4" rows="2" cols="60" maxlength="100" disabled></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        <!--  FIN CUARTO ROW -->
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbox5" value="checkbox5" name="cbox5">¿Tiene cobertura de salud? Describa</label>
              <textarea class="md-textarea form-control" id="ttarea5" name="ttarea5" rows="2" cols="60" maxlength="100" disabled></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input id="btn-agregar-a-tabla" type="button" name="agregar" class="" value="Guardar" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////// FIN DEL MODAL ///////////////////////////////////// -->
```

Comment: Si es bootstrap ya de manera automática es responsive, ahora si dentro no se hace responsive, asegurate de tener un row y un col para dibujar dentro de la modal en el orden que deseas. Igual puedes colocar el codigo de tu modal pára ayudarte mejor

Comment: si ya lo publique...

Comment: Te realize un ejemplo https://jsfiddle.net/fznL4925/ entra y lo pruebas en responsive

Comment: Que quieres exactamente, aumentar el ancho del modal o ajustar el contenido.